# Can we add application icon in notification area of task bar from windows store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, winrt-component

Is it possible to add application icon in notification area of task bar from windows store app.?
which class is responsible for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Store App (WinRT) : NO You can't .

In Windows Form/ WPF ..etc. : Yes you can .

Comment: Many thanks for your replay and information. what is the alternative solution for displaying icon and task bar menu in windows store application

Comment: You need a WinForm OR WPF Desktop app.. Check “Project Centennial” : https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges

Comment: since i am working on windows store application, Can we add menu bar to toast notification from windows store app? OR in which notification method we add menu.Like task bar menu in older application.